# Tkinter Stop Program Execution Button

Tags: python, tkinter, exit

I am attempting to construct a simple game using the Tkinter GUI. The first portion of the game is asking if one wants to play. My Tkinter looks as follows:

```
window = tk.Tk()

window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure([0, 1, 2], minsize=50, weight=1)

lbl_value = tk.Label(master=window, text="Welcome!")
lbl_value.grid(row=0, column=1)

lbl_value = tk.Label(master=window, text="Would you like to play?")
lbl_value.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn_yes = tk.Button(master=window, text="Yes", command=window.destroy)
btn_yes.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")

btn_no = tk.Button(master=window, text="No", command=**??**)
btn_no.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nsew")

window.mainloop()
```

The "Yes" button is operating as intended, and continuing with the rest of the code. The "No" button however, I am not sure how to get it to exit the the running of the program all together (not just the window), or even better, how to get it to open an additional window stating "Maybe next time", then ending the program when that window is exited out of.

Comment: Call `sys.exit` to quit the program.

Comment: thats right. Make that an answer

Comment: So after using sys.exit, the program does stop functioning, but it does not close, it just freezes and states the program is not responding. Is that the best way to stop execution?

Comment: To cleanly quit, create your own function that calls `window.quit()` to stop `mainloop()`, then calls `sys.exit()`. After defining this function, use it when creating `btn_no` (i.e. `... command=this_function)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ***new function*** where you can define a new tkinter screen which will appear when user press **NO button** See

```
def no_button_function():   # function that will be called when user pressed no button
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    new_window.title('See You Next Time')
    # create the good bye message using labels and buttons accordingly
```

and now pass this **function** to ***NO buttton***

```
btn_no = tk.Button(master=window, text="No", command=no_button_function)
btn_no.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nsew")
```

Hope You Got This.
Tick Mark If Satisfied